# Forms Authenticate

Tags: c#, wpf

HI ,
i must create an application with a Forms Authentication in WPF, so i create a database(**UserId,Username,Password,PasswordQuestion,PassworAnswer**) and store data with Linq ToSQL but i don't know the right procedure how to create  LoginForm to authenticate  the username and password with Linq ToSQl and set up the roles for each user.
Do you have any idea or advice to do it right?

Thanks

Bye

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should look into creating a roles table first.

With that said, your LINQ query would look something like this:

```
var result = 
  (
    from c in dataContext where username == Username and password == Password 
    select c
  )
```

Very vague question, though. If you can clarify, you'll get better results.

Comment: Hi lan P,
infact i'm a bit confuse about the procedure to authenticate the username and password in WPF.
My purpose is to create a forms Authentication with Roles fer each user but i did not find out some a good example on internet.
Do you have a good example to show me about my idea?
Thanksa lot!!!